# Get the records which don't match the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables that have data like this:

Table `CON_MEMBER`:

| CONTAINER_DATA_BO | CONTAINER_NUMBER_BO |
| --- | --- |
| PARENT_REF_001 | CHILD_REF_001 |
| PARENT_REF_001 | CHILD_REF_002 |

Table `CON_DATA`:

| HANDLE | CONTAINER_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| CHILD_REF_001 | CHILD_001 |
| CHILD_REF_002 | CHILD_002 |

Table `CON_CUSTOM_DATA`:

| CONTAINER_DATA_BO | DATA_FIELD | DATA_ATTR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CHILD_REF_001 | QTY | 10 |
| CHILD_REF_001 | CLASS | CLASS 1 |
| CHILD_REF_001 | MAT | MAT 1 |
| CHILD_REF_001 | TYPE | BARREL |
| CHILD_REF_001 | TRANSPORT | 1 |
| CHILD_REF_002 | QTY | 100 |
| CHILD_REF_002 | CLASS | CLASS 2 |
| CHILD_REF_002 | MAT | MAT 2 |
| CHILD_REF_002 | TYPE | DRUM |

Now I have written a query that will get all the child container numbers against the parent container for which the `CON_CUSTOM_DATA.TRANSPORT` is not 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    cd.CONTAINER_NUMBER 
FROM 
    CON_MEMBER cm1 
INNER JOIN 
    CON_MEMBER cm2 ON cm1.CONTAINER_NUMBER_BO = cm2.CONTAINER_DATA_BO
INNER JOIN 
    CON_DATA cd ON cd.HANDLE = cm1.CONTAINER_NUMBER_BO
LEFT JOIN 
    CON_CUSTOM_DATA ccd ON cd.HANDLE = ccd.CONTAINER_DATA_BO
WHERE 
    cm1.CONTAINER_DATA_BO = 'PARENT_REF_001' 
    AND ccd.DATA_ATTR <> '1'
```

But the query returns both the child "CHILD_002" as well as "CHILD_001". What is am expecting from above query is to get the Child Container Number "CHILD_002", Since for this container TRANSPORT is not 1.

Please help me achieve this output.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT cd.CONTAINER_NUMBER 
FROM CON_MEMBER cm
     JOIN CON_DATA cd ON cm.CONTAINER_NUMBER_BO=cd.HANDLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CON_CUSTOM_DATA ccd
                  WHERE cd.HANDLE = ccd.CONTAINER_DATA_BO
                        AND ccd.DATA_FIELD='TRANSPORT'
                        AND ccd.DATA_ATTR=1);
```